# How to get attribute value of a custom tag in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to create a *custom tag* using angularJs. This tag has an attribute named `data`. `data` gets it value like this `<skillviz data="{{user.info}}"></skillviz>`. `user.info` is a JSON object. But when i try to access this `data` attribute in my directive definition, I get `undefined`. What is the correct way to do this ?

**html code**

```
<div id="info-box" ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:orderProp">            
          <div id="skill-block">
            <skillviz height="50" data="{{user.skills}}"></skillviz>
          </div>
      </div>
```

`users` is a JSON type object, declared in the controller. So basically `users` will be a list(array) of

```
{"first_name": "Tifanny",

        "last_name": "Maxwell",
        "skills": [
            {"name": "Java", "score": 4.8, "color" : "red"},
            {"name": "C++", "score": 4.0, "color" : "blue"},
        ]
    },
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('yott', []).directive('skillviz', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.html("<script>alert(" + attrs['data'] + ")</script>");
        });
    }
  }
});
```

alert box pops up saying **undefined**

Comment: I just changed `element.html("<script>alert(" + attrs['data'] + ")</script>");` to `alert(attrs['data']);`, then it worked for me. http://plnkr.co/k7VCGMpYISBkm5iOtTjp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$observe` to observe changes to the attribute:

```
attrs.$observe('data', function(value) {
  console.log('data has changed value to ' + value);
});
```

And `$set` to change value:

```
attrs.$set('data', 'new value');
```

Alternatively you can pass/link it into the directive scope using `@` (bind a local scope), `&` (provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope) or `=` (set up bi-directional binding) – explained [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#directivedefinitionobject)

```
angular.module('yott', []).directive('skillviz', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope { data: "=data" },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.html("<script>alert(" +scope.data + ")</script>");
            });
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: In addition, it's all right to access the attribute value by `attrs['data']` or `attrs.data`. See the [examples](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#Attributes).

Comment: There should be a semicolon after `scope`, and `= data` should be `=data`, or simply `=`.

Answer (score 20):

Let's say you have the following markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" data-id="someCustomValue">
</div>
```

Now in your controller you can do the following to access **data-id**:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $attrs) {
  console.log($attrs.id); // Prints 'someCustomValue'
});
```

Comment: this is invalid